# Which paypal solution to use?

Tags: paypal

I just noticed that paypal now has a number of solutions to accept payment, and per this own page, it doesn't really compare their difference in a nice way: 
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/accept-payments/

Does anyone happen to know (I am using C#/.net, but JS is also OK), if I want to have a customized checkout, in which I can customize the look and feel, and allow customers to enter/select shipping address (which is saved in the site's own database), which paypal method I should use?

Thanks! (also if any document that explain better the differences of the above different ways of accept payment, it would be great!)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to completely customize everything then the [PayPal Payments Pro Payflow Edition](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/products/payflow-gateway/) is a viable solution. 
Here is the link to [Sample Code](https://devtools-paypal.com/integrationwizard/ccpayflow/code.php) C# is one of the programming languages offered in the Sample Payflow Code.
You will need to build your form/shopping cart and then the Sample Code can be used to make the payment request to process the payments. The Entire Transaction will take place place on your website from start to finish.
If you want PayPal to handle the payment portion with a customer leaving your site to use PayPal as the Payment method and then returning to your site to complete the payment, [Express Checkout](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/products/express-checkout/) is the other option that will work.
 You can make an API call to PayPal to get the Shipping information from PayPal and then store the shipping info in your own database.
Here is the [Express Checkout Sample Code](https://devtools-paypal.com/integrationwizard/ecpaypal/code.php)

Comment: Thanks. How about the "Braintree v.zero" method? Looks like paypal lists it as the first one, so I guess they want people to use it?